# JTree Editor- Where is getCellEditorValue() called?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

When a device editor is set for a `JTree`, when/where is the method `getCellEditorValue` called after cell editing has stopped? I need to modify the behavior where this method is called in order to allow the Editor to update multiple nodes instead of just a single node.

Can someone provide an example of overriding this behavior?

```
DeviceEditor deviceEditor = new DeviceEditor(nodes);
itemTree.setCellEditor(deviceEditor);


    deviceEditor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("ACTION COMMAND= " + ae.getActionCommand());
        if ("Update".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            //get the Device From the editor.
            //update all the nodes' userObjects to the values of the editor except the ones with <Multiple Values>
            //stopEditing expects an Object from DeviceEditor. We need a way to stopEditing without providing an object. 
            itemTree.stopEditing(); //update the nodes     

        }
        if ("Cancel".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            itemTree.cancelEditing();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If I had found the answer I wouldn't be asking the question here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP mistakes SO for a code generation machine.

Answer (score 0):

- `JTree#stopEditing` calls the component's UI delegate's (`TreeUI`) `stopEditing` method
- `BasicTreeUI#stopCellEditing` (which is a good place to start) calls the `TreeCellEditor`'s `stopCellEditing` method
- `DefaultTreeCellEditor#stopCellEditing` (which is a good place to start) calls it's editor delegate's () `stopCellEditing`
- `DefaultCellEditor#stopEditing` (which is the default instance of `TreeCellEditor` used by `DefaultCellEditor` and a good place to start) fires a `editingStopped` event to the registered `CellEditorListener` listeners
- Which takes us back to `BasicTreeUI`, which uses a `private` class to handle the event, which through a series of hops, calls `TreeModel#valueForPathChanged`

So, the answer to your question is "it's complicated" and not guaranteed to be the same for every instance of `JTree` (since the UI delegate can change the path of operations).

The primary take away is this.  You have two possible solutions...

1. Add a `CellEditorListener` to every `TreeCellEditor` of the tree.  This is error prone, as you will likely be fighting the `JTree` and the state of the model will be undetermined
2. Use the `TreeModel` the way it's suppose to be used.  It already provides a `vaueForPathChanged` which provides you with all the information you need to determine which cell was modified and the new value to be applied to the cell.  The model should also be generating appropriate change events and this method could be called independently of the `JTree`, making it a perfect choice

Comment: So if my editor edits all the selected nodes, how do i then pass all the nodes that were edited to the model via the getCellEditorValue()? I basically want to pass a collection of nodes that were edited to the model for it to update. Can you demonstrate this?

Comment: Are you editing the table directly? How does it maintain the selection information?  I would have thought that the selection would have been invalidated when editing started?

Comment: Its a JTree that I'm editing. I allow for multiple node selection and pass all the selected nodes to the editor. On "itemTree.stopEditing()", I'm currently executing Runnables to update the info for all the nodes, and then just return the first node from the list of nodes in "getCellEditorValue. It seems like there should be a way to pass the entire list of nodes back with "getCellEditorValue" and just have the TreeModel update, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: *"It seems like there should be a way to pass the entire list of nodes back with "getCellEditorValue""* - The API doesn't provide that functionality, you can clearly see that by reading the Docs.   The best you could do is trap the model state change event and update the list of previous selected nodes

Comment: Would updating the nodes not also fire the model state changed? So there is basically no mechanism to allow the editing of multiple nodes simultaneously?

Comment: *"Would updating the nodes not also fire the model state changed?"* - It would do it anyway, but you would be in position to determine the "why" and if you should respond to it. *"So there is basically no mechanism to allow the editing of multiple nodes simultaneously?"* Not an existing one